# Open file in a different directory

Tags: c, file

I have to do a simple task. I have to open a file which is in a directory. I have the .c file in src, when I compile I move the programs (a.out) in the a bin directory. I want to read a file in the directory asset. All these folders are in a main folder.

If I do this

```
FILE* fp = fopen("../asset/team_list", "r");
```

it won't open the file. Why can't I open the file in that directory?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925241/how-to-open-a-text-file-thats-not-in-the-same-folder?rq=1

Comment: @Amk,What is the error saying ? If error found using perror function

Comment: As explained in the duplicate, `fopen` is *relative to the `cwd`*. In this case you are most likely going up a level (`..`) when you should not. **If this is not the case** then your question does not contain enough information to answer it (which, to be honest, it already does not).

Answer (score 0):

guess you forgot to put the extension of your file

```
FILE* fp = fopen("../asset/team_list.doc", "r");
```

Comment: @Amk relative file names are relative to the current working directory, which might not be where the executable is located. Which directory are you at when you run your program ?

Answer (score 0):

Find what error you get using perror/explicit mention of error message and expect a possible reply from stackoverflow.

- Make sure you are pointing out to the correct directory where the file is present from the PWD from where your program is being executed.

Answer (score 0):

Relative paths are relative to the current working directory of the process, which might not be the same location as the binary file.  So, if you are in `/home/user/` and you run `./project/bins/my.exe` then your current working directory is `/home/user/`, relative paths need to be relative to that location.

You can try a few things to help with this issue.  First, after the failed open you could examine `errno` to see why the open failed, is it permissions, invalid path?

Alternatively you might have access to the strace program, this traces system calls, like `open` from your application, and will allow you to see the failed system call.  Try `strace ./project/bins/my.exe`, you'll see a lot of output, dig through this looking for the failed open call, and try to figure out why this is failing, again the `errno` will be included in the trace to help understand the failure.

Lastly, you could just add a call to `getcwd` to your program and print the result (as a debugging aid), this places the current working directory into a buffer, something like this:

```
char buffer [PATH_MAX + 1];
getcwd (buffer, PATH_MAX + 1);
printf (buffer);
```