# I am having trouble opening a .txt file in my C++ program

Tags: c++

I have put it under the Source Files folder.  I have set my working directory to $(SolutionDir)$(Configuration)\   (im not sure if that is right, i saw it somewhere) could someone help me troubleshoot.

```
int main()
{
    cout << "program running" <<endl;
    pair<int, unsigned int> mypair;

    ifstream myfile;
    myfile.open("numbers.txt", ios::in);
    if (!myfile.is_open()){
        cerr << "can't open input file" << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << "file opened" << endl;
    }
    getchar();
    myfile.close();
}
```

...output is: can't open input file

Comment: I suggest putting the txt file in the same folder as the .exe and set the directory to `$(OutDir)`

Comment: Which operating system & standard C++ library & compiler? You migjht use `perror` on failure!

Comment: i think this should help you :
  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2925241/how-to-open-a-text-file-thats-not-in-the-same-folder

Comment: I am using windows 7 enterprise and Visual Studio 10.    Sorry I am so bad but how can I set the folder to the exe. I can't seem to find it.

Comment: There is also include as a resource and "Copy to..." output directory on build.  combined with Borgleaders suggestion.

Comment: i have already tried using an absolute path :(

Comment: @jajajJohn _"i have already tried using an absolute path :("_ For which OS in particular? How your absolute path did look like? Did you use the correct path separators `'\\'`/ `'/'`? There are too many reasons why this could fail, entirely depending on the context you're not describing in your question.

Comment: None of the code you've presented will output "cannot open file", so either you've mis-typed your code, or you've misrepresented the output you actually get, or the output is not coming from that code.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ If you read his comment he says "I am using windows 7 enterprise and Visual Studio 10"

Comment: @Borgleader I actually missed it, but tagging the OS would be better anyways.

Comment: @jajajJohn _"..output is: `cannot open file`"_ That's a lie, isn't it?

Comment: absolute path i used:  \\studentfiles.myuniveristy.edu\\storage$\\Personal\\projectNumbers.txt                            haha okay i got lazy the ACTUAL output is " can't open input file"

Comment: PRAISE THE LORDE. I managed to open a file. THANK YOU GUYS i will reply with how i did in in a min.

Answer (score 2):

To figure out what directory you're pointing to, try to create a new file instead of opening one:

```
std::ofstream("out_test.txt");
```

Then you can find that file searching with File Explorer into the solution dir.

Comment: it went to  H:\Personal\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Project1\Debug

Answer (score 1):

There is such thing as current directory for an application. When you run an app from VS working directory would be current one.

If you specify file name with relative path (or no path at all) OS will try to find that file relative to that directory. Where executable file and especially source file(s) are located completely irrelevant. So solution could be either set working directory to where `numbers.txt` is located (or move `nubers.txt` there), or use relative path something like `foobar/numbers.txt` or even `../foobar/numbers.txt` etc or use absolute path.

Answer (score 1):

okay I managed to figure it out..with help :)   I did what Paulo M said :

```
To figure out what directory you're pointing to, try to create a new file instead of opening one:

std::ofstream("out_test.txt");

Then you can find that file searching with File Explorer into the solution dir.
```

After I figured out where the file got sent I added a new file w/ some integers to that dir and made sure the working directory was the same.I'm not sure if i had to change it? (can files be sent elsewhere?).

I had tried to do this before but I was not able to move my txt file into this directory by copy paste..so gave up. But anyhow I just right clicked/new text document/ and edited the doc with some numbers. then changed my program to open this  new document. 
saving file directly to the directory also worked. :) :) :) 
but i am curious why I couldn't just paste it there?